# #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ... Jutts

Tags: mysql, database

**I have created tables in MySQL Workbench as shown below :**

**Categories Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
`categoryId` int(11) primary key auto_incremnt NOT NULL,
  `categoryName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryDescription` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryPicture` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostDate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `LastInsertID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=45 ;
```

**Products Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`proId` int(11) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `categoryId` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryId`) REFERENCES `categories` (`categoryId`) ,
  `proName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proPath` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proPrice` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `proQuantity` decimal(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proImage` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostDate` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

> I'm having a bit of a strange problem, I'm trying to add a foreign key
>   to one table that references another, but it is failing for some
>   reason. With my limited knowledge of MySQL, the only thing that could
>   possibly be suspect is that there is a foreign key on a different
>   table referencing the one I am trying to reference.

Please help me out as soon as possible .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should create the `categoryId` column before assigning it in a foreign key,

`categoryId int(11) NOT NULL,`

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`proId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `categoryId` INT ,
  `proName` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proPath` VARCHAR(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proPrice` FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  `proQuantity` DECIMAL(38,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `proImage` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostDate` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  FOREIGN KEY (`categoryId`) REFERENCES `categories` (`categoryId`) 
) ENGINE=INNODB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```